# Xml preview not rendering after adding Splash screen API (You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity”)

Tags: android, xml

[Xml preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU1iS.png)[Manifest Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiCWI.png)After adding the latest API introduced by google in Android 12
i.e changing android:theme in Manifest file
the xml previews are not loading for activities in which material views are added...

Tried adding theme to every activity in androidmanifest file
but it didn't work